# Can I enable Azure AD Domain Services in a Classic virtual network?

Tags: azure

Can I get detailed answer for this? Already referred other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic virtual networks aren't supported for new deployments. Existing managed domains deployed in Classic virtual networks continue to be supported until they're retired on March 1, 2023.